# C#: How to make sure a settings variable exists before attempting to use it from another assembly?

Tags: c#, settings, settings.settings

I have the following:

```
using CommonSettings = MyProject.Commons.Settings;

public class Foo
{
    public static void DoSomething(string str)
    {
        //How do I make sure that the setting exists first?
        object setting = CommonSettings.Default[str];

        DoSomethingElse(setting);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on what type `CommomSettings.Default` is, a simple null check should be fine:

```
if(setting != null)
    DoSomethingElse(setting);
```

If you want to check BEFORE trying to retrieve the setting, you need to post the Type of CommonSettings.Default. It looks like a Dictionary so you might be able to get away with:

```
if(CommonSettings.Default.ContainsKey(str))
{
    DoSomethingElse(CommonSettings.Default[str]);
}
```

Comment: I thought he was more asking how to _ensure_ that the setting is present, not just to check whether it is present.

Comment: @Uwe - You might be right. I couldn't tell from the wording in the OP's question. I added something for that case as well.

Comment: It is however a Settings.settings file is constructed... I don't think it's a Dictionary type since `CommonSettings.Default.ContainsKey(...)` is not in the intellisense.

Comment: This doesn't work with Properties.Settings.Default.  @Salle55 provided a good solution that does work with Properties.Settings.Default below.

Comment: For me: `CommonSettings.Default.Context.ContainsKey(str)`  (VS 2019, .NET4.5)

Answer (score 30):

If you are using a `SettingsPropertyCollection` you have to loop and check which settings exists yourself it seems, since it doesn't have any Contains-method.

```
private bool DoesSettingExist(string settingName)
{
   return Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Cast<SettingsProperty>().Any(prop => prop.Name == settingName);
}
```

Comment: thx salle55. great work. 
For those that don't have 
 using System.Configuration
please add prefix  System.Configuration. to SettingsProperty>

Answer (score 6):

```
try
{
    var x = Settings.Default[bonusMalusTypeKey]);
}
catch (SettingsPropertyNotFoundException ex)
{
    // Ignore this exception (return default value that was set)
}
```

Comment: Some description would be useful!

Answer (score 5):

This is how you deal with it:

```
if(CommonSettings.Default.Properties[str] != null)
{
    //Hooray, we found it!
}
else
{
    //This is a 'no go'
}
```

Comment: this condition will be true even you haven't set it before. I think OP wanted to know this settings have set before.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
public static void DoSomething(string str)
{
    object setting = null;

    Try
    {
        setting = CommonSettings.Default[str];
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.out.write(ex.Message);
    }

    if(setting != null)
    {
        DoSomethingElse(setting);
    }
}
```

This would ensure the setting exists - you could go a bit further and try and catch the exact excetion - e.g catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex)

Comment: Just seen your update Justin - Your solution looks allot cleaner :)