# C# Properties.Settings.Default

Tags: c#

How to ensure that retrieving value from `Properties.Settings.Default` exists?
For example, when I use this code:

```
folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = (string)Properties.Settings.Default["SelectedPath"];
```

and value `SelectedPath` does not exist, I get the followng exception:

> System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyNotFoundException' occurred in
>   System.dll

How can I avoid this exception?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: How to make sure a settings variable exists before attempting to use it from another assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647796/c-how-to-make-sure-a-settings-variable-exists-before-attempting-to-use-it-from)

Comment: I saw this question but I didn't understand how to use "CommonSettings.Default.ContainsKey(str)". How to get CommonSettings?

Comment: It isn't very clear why you'd write code like this.  Use Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedPath and the compiler will tell you that you got it wrong.  Which is the point of using the settings designer.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to do all things in runtime, like I used with registry in early times. But it seems that I don't have another way than use settings designer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless that collection provides a method to check whether a given key exists then you will have to wrap the code in a `try..catch` block.

```
 try{
     folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = (string)Properties.Settings.Default["SelectedPath"];
 }catch(System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyNotFoundException)
 {
     folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = "";  // or whatever is appropriate in your case
 }
```

If the `Default` property implements the `IDictionary` interface you can use the `ContainsKey` method to test that the given key exists before trying to access it, like so:

```
 if(Properties.Settings.Default.ContainsKey("SelectedPath"))
 {
     folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = (string)Properties.Settings.Default["SelectedPath"];
 }else{
     folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = ""; // or whatever else is appropriate in your case
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method to check for the existence of a key:

```
    public static bool PropertiesHasKey(string key)
    {
        foreach (SettingsProperty sp in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
        {
            if (sp.Name == key)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: While the method shown below works, it does so at the cost of an exception. OTOH, the method shown above avoids raising exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

try this:(our friend 'Mike Dinescu' mention that with no details - Edit: he has provided details now)

```
try
{
    folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = 
     (string)Properties.Settings.Default["SelectedPath"]
}
catch(System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyNotFoundException e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message); // or anything you want
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //if any exception but above one occurs this part will execute
}
```

I hope this solution solve your problem :)

Edit : Or without using try catch :

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Properties.Settings.Default["SelectedPath"]))
{
   folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = 
         (string)Properties.Settings.Default["SelectedPath"]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way without using try ... catch(System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyNotFoundException e)?

Answer (score 0):

you can set default `null` value for the variable .
add this code to `Settings.Designer.cs` file :

```
[UserScopedSetting]
[DebuggerNonUserCode]
[DefaultSettingValue(null)] // <-- set default value
public string test1
{
    get
    {
        return (string)this[nameof(test1)];
    }
    set
    {
        this[nameof(test1)] = (object)value;
    }
}
```

then check :

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.test1 != null)
```